# Prompt user to select sheet to copy

Tags: excel, vba

As part of a larger macro, I have code that:

- opens a workbook,
- copies the first sheet of that workbook to a new sheet in the current workbook,
- then closes the newly opened workbook.

This code works, but now I want to modify it *so the user can select which sheet to copy over*

Here's the code  I have:

```
Dim wb3 As Workbook
Set wb3 = ThisWorkbook

Dim wb_mainFile As Workbook
Dim strMainFile As String

strMainFile = Range("G4").Value
'G4 is the cell that contains the path to the workbook that is to be opened

Set wb_mainFile = Workbooks.Open(strMainFile)
ThisWorkbook.Activate
wb_mainFile.Sheets(1).Copy _
After:=wb3.Sheets(wb3.Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet3"
wb_mainFile.Close
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there isn't a way to select a sheet like this - so this is a bit of hack.

This requires the user to select a cell on the required sheet:

```
Sub Foo()

Dim mySheet As Excel.Worksheet

Set mySheet = Application.InputBox("Select a cell on the sheet you want to use:", Type:=8).Parent

MsgBox "Chosen sheet is " & mySheet.Name

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bring up the list of tabs with the built in CommandBar (that pops up in the bottom left on clicking)

```
Sub CrowsFlag()
Dim cbTool As CommandBar
Set cbTool = CommandBars("workbook tabs")
cbTool.ShowPopup
End Sub
```

[image]